# ASP.NET checkbox won't postback when onclick is defined

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, postback

I intend to answer my own question here - I think this could be difficult to fathom. I have two checkboxes, the second of which has a postback, which should only fire if the first one is checked. Here's what I wrote

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTC" runat="server" Text="I have read and accept the Terms & Conditions" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick =" var bOK = document.getElementById('chkTC').checked; if (!bOK) { alert('You must agree to the Terms and Conditions'); } return bOK; " />
```

The onclick code is a copy the code I use if I want to determine if a button should postback.

However, there was no postback from the second checkbox, even if the first was ticked.

Answer (score 1):

I found that ASP.NET doesn't have a defined 'onclick' property for checkboxes, but will pass any onclick code supplied through to the generated HTML. However, it also utilises the onclick attribute to effect the postback. The onclick code that I supplied was prepended to the code that makes the postback happen. And because I used a return statement, it was not being executed. Sorry if this is obvious - it wasn't to me.

So the fix is to only execute a return when I don't want the postback

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick =" var bOK = document.getElementById('chkTC').checked; if (!bOK) { alert('You must agree to the Terms and Conditions'); return false; }" />
```

Comment: It does have an `OnCheckedChanged`

Comment: is that not server-side?

Comment: Yes. If you want client side use `OnClientClick`. I though you wanted a PostBack when the textbox changed.

Comment: I want postback to be conditional - I want to do a check in JS that might mean I don;t postback. Can I do that by returning false from OnClientClick?